# Proving irregularity using Myhill-Nerode theorem

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I need to prove that `L = { 0^(3n)1^(2n) | n>0 }` is irregular using The Myhill-Nerode theorem

I understand I need to demonstrate that it is not a finite union of equivalence classes, by using the the concept of distinguishability between strings:
strings `x` and `y` are distinguishable if there exists some string `z` such that `xz` is in L but `yz` is not in `L`, or vice versa.

However, if we add any `z` to a word in the language `L`, it will no longer be a member of `L`. For example, adding 0's is not allowed because `0` can only come before `1` in `L`. Adding 1's is also not allowed because it would result in a word of the form `0(3n)1^(2n+i)`, which breaks the `3:2` ratio of 0's and 1's that is required for a word to be in `L`.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myhill-Nerode theorem speaks about splitting all words to classes, not only words in $L$.

Words in $L$ are indeed all equivalent: if we add an empty word to word from $L$, we (of course) get word from $L$, and if we add any non-empty word, we get word not from $L$.

But words $x_n = 0^{3n}$ for different $n$ are not equivalent: if we have words $x_n$ and $x_m$ with $n \neq m$, then adding $1^{2n}$ to both we get $0^{3n}1^{2n} \in L$ and $0^{3m}1^{2n} \notin L$. Thus we have infinite number of pairwise non-equivalent words, and so infinite number of equivalence classes.

Comment: @mihalid thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was missing.